# Ansible - Docker / container doesn't start automatically after reboot

Tags: docker, ansible

I have the following ansible code:

```
- name: Run mycontainer
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ my_container }}"
    image: "my_container:{{ my_container_version }}"
    pull: true
    state: started
    restart_policy: always
```

When I reboot the machine and the machine is back to normal, the container status is: `Exited (1) 6 minutes ago`. When I restarted it manually by `docker restart mycontainer`, its up again.

As I understand, `restart_policy: always` should handle this case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that Ansible didn't change the restart_policy param to always, checked by `docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy }}" mycontainer`.

just after removing the container, and deploy it again - it was fixed.